# How to use NY timezone for timenow in alertcondition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The title says it all.
I want to use alertcondition and provide `current_time={{timenow}}` for it. but the time that is shown is not the NY time, in my system and chart I do have NY time though.
Is there a way to make `{{timenow}}` to show the NY time?

Comment: Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63041879/pine-script-how-to-display-current-time-in-charts-timezone-on-label-at-every)

Comment: that does not work for alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63041879/pine-script-how-to-display-current-time-in-charts-timezone-on-label-at-every)

As explained here,

> Pine scripts have no visibility on the chart's timezone you may have
> selected manually. That only affects the display of the chart.

The interesting thing is that there is a [@PineCoders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11806240/pinecoders-lucf) framework that converts *'Time Exchage to Time Chart'*

With [hour](https://tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_hour) and [minute](https://tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_minute), allows you to set the return value to a specified time zone (NY time in your case)

On the other hand, you cannot use an argument of type 'series string' in *alertcondition*. You must use [alert](https://tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_alert)

Something like that:

```
i_timeZone   = input('GMT-5')//NY Time
current_time = str.tostring(hour(timenow, i_timeZone), '00:') + str.tostring(minute(timenow, i_timeZone), '00:') + str.tostring(second(timenow, i_timeZone), '00')

if yourConditionLongShort
    alert(current_time, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

[image]